# SQL: Filtering for a range of numbers in a LIKE case on a varchar column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to filter for ranges of numbers on a varchar column. I have a list of product titles of TVs and want to put them in buckets of size, e.g. "42 inches or smaller". Is it possible to use something like a <=42 in this statement?

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(table1.TITLE) LIKE '%42 IN%' 
        THEN '42 inches or smaller'
ELSE 'Other' END As TV_Type
```

The like statement needs to also contain text, as model names can contain other numbers and I don't want to capture a TV with the title "Samsung 40 inch tv model 1250" in the 50-inch bucket.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Fab

Comment: Doesn't your table have a column for size?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately there is quite a bit of miscategorisation and a sizeable chunk of all entries are uncategorised.

Comment: Then I would write a query to cleanup the data and after that start using your column.

Comment: Give some distinct values of `TITLE` column.

Comment: Is there any particular format of the title?

Comment: Also tag the correct oracle version

Answer (score -1):

Updated based on new data.

```
with table1 as
(
select '45 inches' as title from dual
union
select '36 inches' from dual
union
select 'Panasonic TX-40C300B 1080p Full HD LED 40 Inch TV' from dual union
select   'UE40H5000 40" Full HD LED Backlit TV' from dual union
select 'Samsung Series 6 JU6500 Smart 4K Ultra HD Curved LED 40 Inch TV' from dual

)
select case when trimsize  <= 42
    THEN '42 inches or smaller'
    ELSE 'Greater than 42 inches'
    end as TV_Type
from(
select case when instr(upper(title),'INCH') > 0 then
trim(substr(title,instr(upper(title),'INCH')-4,3))
when  instr(title,'"') > 0 then
trim(substr(title,instr(title,'"')-2,2))
end as trimsize
from table1) tmp1
```

First I am deciding if your input string has `"` or `INCH` keyword. Based on that I am taking the immidiate previous value and trimming it.

Note: If you have extra spaces between 40 and inches, then this would not work. Also if TV size is in 3 digits then it might not work. But other than than, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for this. You asked for some example titles earlier:

"Panasonic TX-40C300B 1080p Full HD LED 40 Inch TV";
"UE40H5000 40" Full HD LED Backlit TV";
"Samsung Series 6 JU6500 Smart 4K Ultra HD Curved LED 40 Inch TV"

If I understand your solution correctly it would have issues with there being numbers other than the size in inches, right?

Comment: You got to give some other examples of TITLE column. Does it always start with `Samsung XX inch...` ?

Comment: The titles are not uniform unfortunately (see examples above)

Comment: You need to give me a pattern. So if string has keywork `inch` in it, then the previous value is the size. And if it has `"` in it, then its previous value is the size. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Updated the answer. Check if it is working the way you want. If you then accept it by clicking the tick box on left of the answer.